# Line drawn by Graphics type variable disappears when making a label for it

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, label

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.*;

public class NewJFrame extends JFrame {
    private Graphics g1;
    private JLabel label = new JLabel();
    // holds information of all businesses
    private Object[][] busInfo = new Object[10][15];

    public NewJFrame() {
        initComponents();
        g1 = jPanel1.getGraphics();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {
        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 858, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGap(0, 564, Short.MAX_VALUE));
        jButton1.setText("Click Me");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING).addGroup(
                javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING,
                layout.createSequentialGroup().addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addComponent(jButton1).addGap(425, 425, 425))
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(48, 48, 48)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                        .addContainerGap(61, Short.MAX_VALUE)));
        layout.setVerticalGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup().addGap(28, 28, 28)
                        .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE,
                                javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED).addComponent(jButton1)));
        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        printBarChart(2, 1);
        System.out.println(getSize());
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(NewJFrame.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
            new NewJFrame().setVisible(true);
        });
    }

    public void printBarChart(int bestBus, int worstBus) {
        busInfo[0][7] = 24325.08;
        busInfo[1][7] = 15394.59;
        busInfo[2][7] = 186719.84;
        int y = jPanel1.getSize().height;
        int x = jPanel1.getSize().width;
        double balance, maxScale = (double) busInfo[bestBus][7] + 650;
        int sameBusDistance, diffBusDistance = 0, scaleNum, maxPoint;
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; ++i) {
            if (i == 0) {
                diffBusDistance = 0;
            } else {
                diffBusDistance += 65;
            }
            // color of best business
            if (i == bestBus) {
                g1.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
                // color of worst business
            } else if (i == worstBus) {
                g1.setColor(Color.RED);
                // color of other businesses (neither best nor worst)
            } else {
                g1.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            }
            balance = (double) busInfo[i][7];
            sameBusDistance = 25;
            scaleNum = y - 100;
            maxPoint = scaleNum - (scaleNum * (int) balance / (int) maxScale) + 50;
            g1.drawLine(125 + diffBusDistance, y - 50, 125 + diffBusDistance, maxPoint);
            g1.drawLine(125 + sameBusDistance + diffBusDistance, y - 50, 125 + sameBusDistance + diffBusDistance,
                    maxPoint);
            g1.drawLine(125 + sameBusDistance + diffBusDistance, maxPoint, 125 + diffBusDistance, maxPoint);
            jPanel1.add(label);
            jPanel1.setLayout(null);
            label.setSize(100, 50);
            label.setFont(label.getFont().deriveFont(8f));
            label.setLocation(125 + sameBusDistance + diffBusDistance - 30, maxPoint - 50);
            label.setText("" + busInfo[i][7]);
        }
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Line drawn by Graphics type variable disappears when making a label for it
This code is in a for loop for the number of businesses. I will attach a picture of the problem.The first bar works just fine:
[image]

The second however removes the first bar and its label from view:

[image]

Printing labels for Bar Charts causing other bars and their labels to dissapear

Comment: The fact that you're doing graphics, setting layouts and adding components in the same method tells us that whatever you're doing, it's very wrong. The drawing should be done completely separately from any  component additions or removals and from any setting of layouts, and should be done within the paintComponent override of a JPanel or JComponent. Please create and post a valid [mcve] for a more complete answer.

Comment: Suggestions: 1.  Create a class that extends from JPanel, do all drawing within the JPanel's paintComponent method. 2. Call the super's paintComponent method first thing in that override. 3. Avoid null layouts, and in this situation avoid using JLabels for the chart's labels, but rather draw the bar-char'ts text in the same paintComponent method. and 4. Again, show us your [mcve] that encapsulates your problem for us in a small runnable compilable program.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels What I don't understand is why do I need paintComponent method when I just override it and not use any of its native usages? Secondly, You said not to use JLabels for chart labeling? what should I use then?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels my post was as minimal as possible I just showed the code that prints my bar charts as well as two pictures of the output.

Comment: `"why do I need paintComponent method when I just override it and not use any of its native usages?"` -- 1. you **are** using its "native usage" by calling the `super.paintComponent(g);` method in your override. 2. You don't tell us how you otherwise are getting your Graphics object to draw with. If you're calling `getGraphics()` on a component to get your Graphics object, the object returned is not stable/durable. To see, simply minimize and then restore your app and see what happens to your graphics.

Comment: 3. WRT JLabels, it's a lot easier and cleaner to simply draw the text using a Graphics object.

Comment: Your post is **too** minimal -- we can't compile and run it! Please read the [mcve] link to see what I'm requesting. You're posting an uncompilable code snippet, when what helps us would be a small compilable program. Your snippet for instance does not show how you're getting your Graphics obj

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels [link] http://www.mediafire.com/file/e1uyavju48nz92r/InvestmentAnalysisProgram.java this is my program. I couldn't shorten it as the whole program ties together and some numbers are needed printing my chart correctly.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels how to "draw the text using a Graphics object." instead of a label? I really really don't want to use the paintComponent, I just don't see why its useful at all. at least in my case.

Comment: I appreciate your help very much my friend

Comment: No links please. Again the posted code should be minimal -- small enough to post here in your question as code-formatted text. Again it should be complete -- runnable. And with regards to paintComponent -- have you minimized and restored your application? Does the drawing disappear when you do this? Have you read the Swing Graphics tutorial that explains *why* to use paintComponent. Please do these things before discounting our advice. You understand that I've been doing Swing GUI programs for over 10 years, right?

Comment: [Swing drawing tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html)

Comment: [More advanced graphics article](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html)

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Ok that's fine If you don't want to open my link, can you just PLEASE tell me how to "draw the text using a Graphics object." instead of a label? that's all I need to know. And like I said I was trying now and I couldn't shorten it because some components are made by the builder so I cant edit them.

Comment: Look up the drawString method in the [Graphics API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html)

Comment: `"some components are made by the builder so I cant edit them."` -- no but you can create a small non-builder GUI, again just minimal.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I literally created a minimal program and tried to post but literly I would copy the whole thing into the code text box and it would leave out some of the code won't let me submit. I ACTUALLY hate my life I dont know anymroe

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Please, my friend just do me a favor and open the file from my links or let me email it to you or something. you don't understand the frustration I'm in right now.

Comment: You may need to also add more explanatory text with your posted code. There needs to be a decent ratio of text to code -- explain your program more, and see if that helps.

Comment: I couldn't open the file if I wanted to -- work related fire wall prevents this from happening. Please keep trying to create and post your minimal program.

Comment: I want to send you a video of my screen copying the minimal code of the file I made and pasting it in the box to show you how its not working for some reason

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I posted the minimal code you just have to add the class declaration, for some reason it refused to add it to the code `import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class NewJFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {`

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I seriously appreciate you help man.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels By the way thanks alot man I figured it out by just using the drawString method, I just didnt know it existed, I didnt use labels anymore. Thank you very much that was all I needed :)

Answer (score 1):

Again, I suggest that you don't use `getGraphics()` called on a *component*. By now you should have minimized and restored your GUI to see that the drawing is not stable when you minimize and restore the GUI.  I suggest that you draw in the paintComponent of your JPanel.

There is an exception however -- if you draw in a BufferedImage, you can use a Graphics object obtained from it, and then display the image in an ImageIcon in a JLabel. For example in the code below I create a JLabel filled with an empty image (to give it size). I then fill the image with some bar chart data on button press, put the image into an ImageIcon and then set the JLabel with that icon by calling `setIcon(...)` on it:

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.swing.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class DrawInImage extends JPanel {
    private static final int IMG_W = 900;
    private static final int IMG_H = 700;
    private static final int GAP = 20;
    private BufferedImage img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
    private Icon icon = new ImageIcon(img);
    private JLabel label = new JLabel(icon);
    private int[] data = { 4, 2, 9, 7, 3, 8, 2, 8 };

    public DrawInImage() {
        JPanel btnPanel = new JPanel();
        btnPanel.add(new JButton(new AbstractAction("Press Me") {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                printBarChart();
            }
        }));
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        add(label);
        add(btnPanel, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
    }

    private void printBarChart() {
        // create new image
        img = new BufferedImage(IMG_W, IMG_H, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        Graphics2D g2 = img.createGraphics(); // get image's graphics
        g2.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
        g2.setFont(new Font(Font.SANS_SERIF, Font.BOLD, 18));

        // get sizes of drawing area
        int totalWidth = IMG_W - 2 * GAP;
        int totalHeight = IMG_H - 2 * GAP;
        // number of columns including gaps
        int columns = 2 * data.length + 1;

        // calc the max data + 1
        int maxData = 0;
        for (int i : data) {
            if (i > maxData) {
                maxData = i;
            }
        }
        maxData++; // + 1

        for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            int x1 = GAP + ((2 * i + 1) * totalWidth) / columns;
            int x2 = GAP + ((2 * i + 2) * totalWidth) / columns;
            int y1 = GAP + (totalHeight * (maxData - data[i])) / maxData;
            int y2 = GAP + totalHeight;

            float hue = (float) i / (float) data.length;
            Color c = Color.getHSBColor(hue, 1f, 1f);
            g2.setColor(c);
            g2.fillRect(x1, y1, x2 - x1, y2 - y1);
            g2.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            String text = "Data " + (i + 1);
            int strX = x1;
            int strY = y1 - GAP / 2;
            g2.drawString(text, strX, strY);
        }

        g2.dispose(); // dispose of graphics objects *we* create
        icon = new ImageIcon(img); // create new icon
        label.setIcon(icon); // display in label
    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Draw In Image");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(new DrawInImage());
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> createAndShowGui());
    }
}
```

Which displays as

[image]

Comment: @HovercrafFullOfEels thanks for all that, I will try to learn from it, However, My program can't be this sophisticated because its for school and also has to look the same way in the picture I attached. I truly appreaciate your efforts for helping me my friend.